# I want to assign string value to numeric number in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

zom$country.code is int.
zom$Country.Code<- c(1,14,30,37,94,148,162,166,184,189,191,208,214,215,216)

```
r <-c(India,Australia,Brazil,Canada,Indonesia,NewZealand,Phillipines,Qatar,Singapore,southAfrica,SriLanka,Turkey,UAE,UnitedKingdom,UnitedStates)
```

I want a output like:

```
zom$Country.Code <- c(India,Australia,Brazil,Canada,Indonesia,NewZealand,Phillipines,Qatar,Singapore,southAfrica,SriLanka,Turkey,UAE,UnitedKingdom,UnitedStates)
```

How can I solve this problem in R.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Users here expect you to (1) have demonstrated research, (2) present a code attempt including, (3) sample data, and (4) your expected output. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions and how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: In particular, what do you mean by assign, what is the logic for deciding what country gets what number, what is the format your data is in, how many numbers there are

Comment: Is `data$e` supposed to be a vector of row-indices into `r`, or factor levels, or what? Please explain. Also, use `str()` and `dput()` on your dataframes to understand their structure, then tell us what we need to know to understand your issue.

Comment: data$e is an int type.

Comment: @vidhiamin - The vector assignment in the last line of code in your 5th edit generates an error in R because the country name strings should be within quotes, as I illustrate in my updated answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `factor()` function can be used to associate a vector of numbers with a set of labels. For example:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,2,3,4,4)

theLabels <- c("India","Canada","United States","Mexico")

y <- factor(x,1:4,theLabels)
y
```

produces the following output:

```
> y <- factor(x,1:4,theLabels)
> y
 [1] India         India         India         Canada        United States
 [6] United States Canada        United States Mexico        Mexico
```

Levels: India Canada United States Mexico

To demonstrate that this answer works with the data provided in the fifth edit of the OP:

```
r <-c("India","Australia","Brazil","Canada","Indonesia","NewZealand",
      "Phillipines","Qatar","Singapore","southAfrica","SriLanka","Turkey","UAE","UnitedKingdom","UnitedStates")
zom<- data.frame(Country.Code=c(1,14,30,37,94,148,162,166,184,189,191,208,214,215,216))

zom$Country.Code <- factor(zom$Country.Code,
                           levels = c(1,14,30,37,94,148,162,166,184,189,191,208,214,215,216),
                           labels = r)

zom$Country.Code
```

...and the output:

```
> zom$Country.Code
 [1] India         Australia     Brazil        Canada        Indonesia     NewZealand    Phillipines   Qatar        
 [9] Singapore     southAfrica   SriLanka      Turkey        UAE           UnitedKingdom UnitedStates 
15 Levels: India Australia Brazil Canada Indonesia NewZealand Phillipines Qatar Singapore southAfrica SriLanka Turkey ... UnitedStates
```

**NOTE:** Once the original codes are converted to a factor, the underlying codes are lost because a side effect of factor is that the factor levels become an ordered list from 1 to the number of unique labels associated with the factor.

An alternative to the `factor()` approach is to create a lookup table of country names and codes, and to merge this with the original data. This approach preserves the original values of `Country.Code`.

To illustrate, we'll create a data frame containing multiple rows of `Country.Code` from the OP, and merge it with a lookup table via `dplyr::inner_join()`. We'll then generate a cross-tab of `Country.Name` and `Country.Code` to illustrate accuracy of the join process.

```
library(dplyr)
# first, build a data frame containg multiple rows with same country code
zom<- data.frame(Country.Code=c(1,14,30,37,94,148,162,166,184,189,191,208,214,215,216,
                                1,14,30,37,94,148,162,166,184,189,191,208,214,215,216,
                                1,14,30,37,94,148,162,166,184,189,191,208,214,215,216))
# second, create lookup table of codes and names, one row per country
countryNames <- data.frame(Country.Code=c(1,14,30,37,94,148,162,166,184,189,191,208,214,215,216),
                           Country.Name= c("India","Australia","Brazil","Canada","Indonesia","NewZealand",
                                           "Phillipines","Qatar","Singapore","southAfrica","SriLanka","Turkey","UAE","UnitedKingdom","UnitedStates"),
     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# use dplyr::inner_join() to join country names 
mergedData <- zom %>% inner_join(countryNames)
table(mergedData$Country.Name,mergedData$Country.Code)
```

...and the output:

```
> table(mergedData$Country.Name,mergedData$Country.Code)

                1 14 30 37 94 148 162 166 184 189 191 208 214 215 216
  Australia     0  3  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  Brazil        0  0  3  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  Canada        0  0  0  3  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  India         3  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  Indonesia     0  0  0  0  3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  NewZealand    0  0  0  0  0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  Phillipines   0  0  0  0  0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  Qatar         0  0  0  0  0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  Singapore     0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
  southAfrica   0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0
  SriLanka      0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0
  Turkey        0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0
  UAE           0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0
  UnitedKingdom 0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0
  UnitedStates  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3
>
```

Comment: How can I add country.name column into another data set? For example, I have a data set called qwe and I want to add one column which stores the country. name value.

Comment: @vidhiamin - does the data frame awe already contain the country.code column?

Comment: yes.@ Len Greski

Comment: @vidhiamin then the code listed above in the `inner_join()` approach will work.